# How to add multiple arrays to object in function return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that takes in an object as a prop and needs to add arrays to it using a `for` loop. My problem is that it only works if a single array is added when it is called. If more than one array is to be added, I receive the error `linkLineItems.push is not a function`, but I thought `.push` could be used to add arrays to objects.

Here is the function:

```
function PrepareSuccessorActivityLinkData(data, existingLinks, linkSetter) {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    let linkLineItems;
    let linkLineItem;
    if (data.activitiesafter[0] != "DEFAULT") {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.activitiesafter.length; i++) {
        linkLineItem = {
          source: data.itemname,
          target: data.activitiesafter[i],
          type: "activity-activity-after"
        };
        if (!linkLineItems) {
          linkLineItems = linkLineItem;
        } else {
          linkLineItems.push(linkLineItem);
        }
      }
    } else {
      continue;
    }
    return linkSetter(linkData => [...existingLinks, linkLineItems]);
  }
}
```

Any help on how to add multiple arrays to an object?

**Edit #1: Sample data for the `existingLinks` or object that I'm trying to add items to**

```
var linksData = [
 {"source": "Do Something", "target": "My Document", "type": "Activity Output"},
 {"source": "My Document", "target": "Operator", "type": "Object Responsible"},
 {"source": "Operator", "target": "Do Something", "type": "Role Activity"}
];
```

**Edit #2: Sample data that's being passed into the function as `data`**

```
[{
 itemname: "Hello World", 
 itemtype: "activity", 
 activitiesafter: ["Do Stuff", "Do Other Stuff"]
}]
```

Comment: You can't push onto an object. Set a property instead `linkLineItems.something = []`

Comment: `push` can only be used on Arrays. It would be helpful if you add some example input/output data. It's a little difficult to tell exactly what your desired behavior is here

Comment: @schu34 I added sample data. The function needs to be able to add more than one array at a time (based on the `activitiesafter` `for` loop.

Comment: key, value are not used, is it intended?. Also if linkLineItems can be as big as your for loop (which ever it is), it should be declared before that for loop (so it has a lifetime greater than the for loop)

Comment: I was just using `key,value` to iterate through the parent object passed in as `data`. `linkLineItems` should be as long as the `for var i = 0...` loop.

Comment: also why do you return linkSetter(...), this will break your outer for loop and iterate only once. Is it intended ?

Comment: Also, code seems very wrong since you iterate on props of data and fill some array not based on the iterated prop but on dataactivitesafter (which ever prop is being iterated). Likely you should provide the content of data and the expected output. I also believe concatenating array is not a problem to you so you could have removed the linkSetter/linkData/existinglinks stuff to focus on the output linkLineItems

Comment: @grodzi I'm using `react` and `linkSetter(...)` is the function in a `react hook` to update the state of `existingLinks`. This is my problem, that I call this function `onSubmit` and I may need to update `existingLinks` with multiple arrays. The context is that this is supposed to handle a `multi-select` input on a form. With each selection in the multi-select creating its own array in the `existingLinks` object.

Comment: @usernick I am not discussing your problem, I am stating that calling linkSetter and so on is not what you have trouble with. The difficulty you encounter is just to build linkLineItems out of data passed as argument. All the context is not that useful. The two things which matter (and that we miss) are the content of data (if need be console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) and the expected linkLineItems which should be constructed

Comment: @grodzi I added edit #2 to the main post to show the `data` being passed into the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some self proclaimed best practices:

1. Avoid if possible for-loops when you don't need indices. (see [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and alike). This allows less variables which pollute your eyes.
2. Make early "continue" or "return" to avoid nesting stuff (e.g `return links` comes first)
3. Try to reduce at max the scope of your variables. This is also achieved here by using forEach

```js
function nameTooLong(data, existingLinks, linkSetter) {
  const moreLinks = data.reduce((links, item) => {
    if (item.activitiesafter[0] === "DEFAULT") {
      return links
    }
    item.activitiesafter.forEach(activity => {
      links.push({
        source: item.itemname,
        target: activity,
        type: "activity-activity-after"
      })
    })
    return links
  }, [])
  return linkSetter(_ => existingLinks.concat(moreLinks))
}

nameTooLong([{
 itemname: "Hello World", 
 itemtype: "activity", 
 activitiesafter: ["Do Stuff", "Do Other Stuff"]
},{
 itemname: "shold be ignored", 
 itemtype: "activity", 
 activitiesafter: ["DEFAULT", "nothing there"]
}], ['toto'], (fn) => console.log('newlinks: ', fn()))
```

If you read 3., we can do better and even avoid manipulating the variable links by using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
function nameTooLong(data, existingLinks, linkSetter) {
  const moreLinks = data.flatMap(item => {
    if (item.activitiesafter[0] === "DEFAULT") {
      return []
    }
    return item.activitiesafter.map(activity => ({
      source: item.itemname,
      target: activity,
      type: "activity-activity-after"
    }))
  })
  return linkSetter(_ => existingLinks.concat(moreLinks))
}

nameTooLong([{
 itemname: "Hello World", 
 itemtype: "activity", 
 activitiesafter: ["Do Stuff", "Do Other Stuff"]
},{
 itemname: "shold be ignored", 
 itemtype: "activity", 
 activitiesafter: ["DEFAULT", "nothing there"]
}], ['toto'], (fn) => console.log('newlinks: ', fn()))
```

Comment: This is awesome, I didn't know about `flatMap`. However, I'm getting the error `data.flatMap is not a function` when plugging the function into my app. It's weird because I can `console.log(data)`, store it as a variable in the console, and `data.flatMap` works there. Any ideas?

Comment: Answering my own question from my last comment. I got it to work if I instantiated the array by wrapping `data` in `[ ]`. So the function starts with `const moreLinks = [data].flatMap(item => {`

Comment: @userNick if data is not an array (in your real work case), then you don't need to iterate over data, just process the plain object!

Answer (score 0):

The push function only works on arrays, not on objects.

And since I don't see any reason `linkLineItems` needs to be an object I would suggest you just make it an array by initialising it with `let linkLineItems = [];`.

Comment: I made some updates to the original post to provide more context, but initializing the array with `[ ]` does not seem to result in the desired result of adding multiple arrays to a parent object.